# R define a matrix without values

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying to write a function in R that will take a Matrix with some kind of structure, and a column vector of values to give to that Matrix.

I.e something like this:

```
         X^2 aXY 0                X^2  0   0
 Mat=    aYX Y^2 bYZ    or Mat1=  0   2X^2 0
         0   bZY Z^2              0    0   3X^2



c(X=1,Y=2,Z=3, a=.3,b=.2)   or   c(X=1)
```

Then the Matrix would be given the values from the vector and I can do my maths on the matrix given.

I am having difficulty defining the Matrix. I don't seem to be able to just define a Matrix of empty variables, that are assigned values later.

I have tried

```
x=as.integer
y=as.integer
z=as.integer


Mat=matrix(c(x,0,0,0,y,0,0,0,z),nrow=3)
values=c(x=.5,y=2,z=3)
```

But I don't know if it is then possible to give the matrix those values.

I can define the values for the variables first, and then define the matrix but that's not quite what I want, I think. I.e-

```
x=.5;y=2,z=3;

Mat=matrix(c(x,0,0,0,y,0,0,0,z),nrow=3)
```

My function will require to know the structure of the Matrix, as well as the values. The only constraints I want is that that it should be a covariance matrix.
Cheers

Edit- I Should point out that my matrices will ideally not be just 3*3 but any sized square and I might want a variable for every position in the lower triangular. (My matrices will always be symmetric.)

Comment: What is your intention for the line `x=as.integer`? It should be something wrong in R language, unless you know what are you doing. Are you trying to declare a variable?

Comment: Will the matrix always be square?

Comment: Only reason I put in as.integer was that It couldn't accept x or y unless I made them something.

Answer (score 0):

Applying your reasoning:

```
f <- function(a,b,x,y,z){matrix(c(x^2, a*x*y, 0, a*x*y, y^2, b*y*z, 0, b*z*y, z^2), nrow=3, ncol=3)}
# Use it!
f(.3,.2,1,2,3)

>
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  1.0  0.6  0.0
[2,]  0.6  4.0  1.2
[3,]  0.0  1.2  9.0
```

It should be straight forward to add an `if` statement inside the function body to check the input variables for the case where only X is defined and return the alternate form.

Note that covariance matrices can be derived using the `cov()` built-in function.

Comment: This will work for a specific matrix structure, but I would like to be able to make any structure with just one function. Otherwise I am back to coding up a huge list of functions that represent every different way a co-variance matrix might be structured in my problem.
I'll have a look at cov() can't believe I haven't come across it yet. Cheers.

Comment: Can you give an example of a second format that you would want to generate with the same function?

Answer (score 0):

Having spoken to some other people, I think the easiest solution is just to have an editable make.matrix function as sugested. This way whoever is using the code just needs to edit the make.matrix function to fit their design, and then call it later. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

I believe something like this is what you are after, you may like to have a play around with passing the actual matrix into the function, here, I have turned the matrix frame into a vector.

```
MakeMatrix<-function(X=0,Y=0,Z=0,MatrixForm){
    #Get the number of entrys in the matrix
    n<-length(MatrixForm)
    #create a matrix with sqrt(n) rows and columns (ie make it square)
    m<-matrix(nrow =sqrt(n), ncol = sqrt(n))

    #Start stroing data
    count = 1
    for(i in 1:sqrt(n)){
        for(j in 1:sqrt(n)){
            #Evaluates the line with the given values provided
            m[i,j]<-eval(parse(text=MatrixForm[count]))

        count = count + 1
        }
    }
    return(m)
}

MF<-c("X^2",0,0,0,"2*X^2",0,0,0,"3*X^2")
MakeMatrix(X=1,MatrixForm=MF)

>      
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    0    0
[2,]    0    2    0
[3,]    0    0    3
```